# R Convert data frame to nc file with 3 dimensions

Tags: r, netcdf

I am trying to convert a data frame that has time (as record), lat, lon and tmp to a nc file that has 3 dimensions. Here is the code that I got so far.

```
lon1 <- ncdim_def( "Lon", "degrees_east", unique(DB$lon))
lat1 <- ncdim_def( "Lat", "degrees_north", unique(DB$lat))
record <- ncdim_def( "record", "files", list_obs$record_uid,unlim=T)
mv <- -999 # missing value to use
tmpmean_ <- ncvar_def( "tmpmean_", "degrees", list(lon1,lat1,record),mv)

time<-list_obs$record_uid

ncnew <- nc_create( "tmpmean_.nc",tmpmean_)

for( i in 1:length(record))
  ncvar_put( ncnew, tmpmean_, DB$tmpmean_, start=c(1,1,i), 
             count=c(-1,-1,1))
```

I get this error message:
"ncvar_put: warning: you asked to write 3128 values, but the passed data array has 103224 entries!"

Comment: Better to directly pass a 3-d array to `ncvar_put` and avoid the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal, the tip helped.